# Правильный вывод элементов списка

Tags: python

Скажите, почему в питоне нельзя так выводить элементы списка и какая есть альтернатива?

```
N = 10
a = []
for i in range(1, N-1):
    a.append(20)
    print(a[i])
```

Ошибка:

```
    print(a[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот поэтому

```
for i in range(1, N-1):
```

а надо так:

```
for i in range(N):
```

индексы списков от 0 считаются

Comment: из ответа совершенно не ясна ошибка. А почему, например, не print(a[i-1]) ?